# Can Facebook unique id been stored on server for verifying?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I'm developing an app on iOS and Andriod. I would like to allow only some Facebook ID to be able to use my app. How can I do that?

Can i put their facebook unique id into my server and when they login, the app will get thier unique id and verify it with the one stored on my server?

But can someone steal other's unique id then loging in random account and use that stoled unique id to get access into my app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some sort of official SDK to authenticate and log your users into your system then the FBID the SDK gives you can not be "spoofed".

You as long as you are using supported methods to authenticate your users (ie: via Facebook itself) you can rest assured that only the "allowed" users as you say will be able to use the application.

---

Keep in mind that using this method you will not be able to prevent other users from installing your application. Your server will only be able to check if the user is "allowed" to use the application after the user has installed and authenticated via Facebook - only then will you have access to their FBID for validation.

---

If you want to totally prevent anyone who is not in a certain group of users from reaching your application at all then you can setup some roles for your application as long as it is left in "Development Mode": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/
Using these settings will allow you to define certain groups of users such as developers or testers and only users specifically listed will be able to install and use your application.

Comment: even through this could be done but in this document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/custom-audiences-for-mobile-apps/ under the section "a couple of things to note" it says "Each call to Facebook's server to generate an app user ID will generate a different ID. Although multiple calls will end up targeting the same person, the app user IDs generated can't be used to correlate across apps or app instances. As such, the app user ID should not be used as a login token or considered to be a unique identifier." which means it will change over time? and can't be used as Unique ID?

Comment: @user23839 - across multiple applications - no.

Comment: But for only my app, it will work fine? and can be used as unique ID? love you xoxo ^o^

Comment: What about if they change the device but using the same Facebook account and the same app? will they get the same FBID ?

Comment: If the Unique ID is very crucial for being allowed to use my app. Should I encrypt it before storing in my database? or I do not have to? If someone know Mr.A Unique ID, can he/she use it to get access into my app? or even he/she know Mr.A Unique ID it still impossible to hack my app? should I verify unique ID from Client-side or from Facebook Server?